# Javascript escape characters ahref html

Tags: javascript, html

How do you escape characters when including a variable in a href, img attributes etc. This does'nt seem to work:

```
var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString2);
var $grouplist = $('#groups');
$.each(myData, function() {
 $('<li><a href="'+ this.url + '"/><img src="'+ this.src + '" class="image0"/></a></li>').appendTo($grouplist);
 });
}
```

Whole function above.

```
$('<li><a href=\"' + this.url + '\"</a></li>').appendTo($grouplist);
```

Comment: Are you asking about the double quotes (you don't need those backslashes), or about encoding the URL from `this.url`? Please give more details about what you mean by "not working".

Comment: JS string encoding, HTML attribute encoding, URL encoding. Start at the lowest level (url), and encode each layer in order.

Comment: Are you trying to find all the `<li>` elements containing `<a>` elements which have `this.url` as their `href` attribute and then call `appendTo` on them? If not what is the aim of code?

Comment: It needs to append a LI to a UL, whilst passing the url value to the href, and "' instead of \"' doesn't work, I though it would do?

Comment: There is two different problems in the HTML code that you create, not related to escaping. In the complete code you are using a self closing anchor tag. In the shortened version you have removed the ending angle bracket of the anchor start tag along with the image tag.

Comment: it's still essentially the same problem, escaping double quotes, for the a href and a img src. I'm looking at items.Push() to append the li instead... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to. Create the element and set the attribute, then you don't need to worry about escaping anything, neither the quotation marks, not the attribute value:

```
$('<li>').append($('<a>', { href: this.url })).appendTo($grouplist);
```

#### Edit:

The code with the image element also:

```
$('<li>').append(
  $('<a>', { href: this.url }).append(
    $('<img>', { src: this.src, 'class': 'image0' })
  )
).appendTo($grouplist);
```

Comment: don't you have to put in the closing </li> ?

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: No, the `$()` function checks for strings that look like `'<li>'` and uses `document.createElement` to create the element instead of parsing the string as HTML code. See the `$(html, props)` overload: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: does that assume that the LI exists already? see my revised code, i'm adding a LI when the function runs.

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: No, the code `$('<li>')` creates a new `li` element. I added code above with the image element also.

Comment: thanks, that shows the li's but does not add the <a> or <img> elements.

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: When I try it, it adds all the elements. Here's my test to compare with: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/w3EfV/

Comment: ah I see, must be how to handle the incoming json data, i've update that fiddle with the full function, I can't get it to display the a / img. Or here http://jsfiddle.net/ULdDc/

Comment: @PeteTheGreek: There are no `url` or `src` properties in your data. Choosing to use jQuery, adding some propferties in the data, and reading from the object in the loop, they show up: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ULdDc/6/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to escape when you have the same quotes. In your case this will work:

```
$('<li><a href="' + this.url + '"</a></li>').appendTo($grouplist);
```

Because the double quotes won't interfere with the single ones.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the double quotes, because they are inside single quotes. Also, you didn't finish the opening a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [window.escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.escape). There is also encodeURIComponent, which is generally preferred if it is user-input.

As others pointed out, you don't need to escape your double quotes there. So try this:

```
$('<li><a href="' + encodeURIComponent(this.url) + '"></a></li>').appendTo($grouplist);
```

Or Guffa's approach:

```
$('<li>').append($('<a>', { href: encodeURIComponent(this.url) })).appendTo($grouplist);
```